# Mechanical Turk: how to avoid HITs from different batches to be collapsed

Tags: mechanicalturk

I have a problem with the distribution of HITs from different batches.

The situation is the following: I have 3 batches with 17 HITs each, and I prepared 3 different templates.

What I would like to do is that whenever a worker accepts my HITs, he is shown the 17 HITs connected to a template, and only those (template 1, batch 1). 
Then, if he chooses to do another 17, he is shown the other 17 HITs (template 2, batch 2), etc.

What seems to happen is that they see more than 17 HITs, in a sequence (batch 1, part of batch 2): how can I prevent batches to be collapsed? I thought it would have been enough to publish different batches via different templates.

Many thanks in advance!
Gabriella

Answer (score 0):

They'll be collapsed in the system if nothing differs between the HITType characteristics of the batch. So, in order to keep them separate, change one of those properties (e.g., the title, description, keywords, etc.). This will assign each batch a distinct HITTypeId and keep them separated in the system.